# Atomic string replacement in PHP

Tags: php, sql, string, replace

In our web application, we have a class which emulates prepared statements for correct escaping of SQL parameters.

Now, I now it would be much better to just use `PDO`, but the app is very old and the refactoring could be quite long, so for the time being I just wanted to fix a bug I found.

Consider this piece of code which uses our classes:

```
$s = Q()->statement("SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = :a AND 2 = :b AND 3 = :c");
$s->bindValue('c', ':b');
$s->bindValue('b', ':a');
$s->bindValue('a', ':c');
var_dump($s->prepared);
```

the first line creates the statement, then some values are bound, then I dump the prepared statement.

The result of this is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = ':c' AND 2 = '':c'' AND 3 = ''':c'''
```

and this happens because the parameters are substituted one at a time from the last to the first.

I also tried doing the replacement in a single function call, using `str_replace()` with array parameters, but to no avail.

So I would like to know if there is a way to make this operation somehow "atomic" so that if a placeholder value is another valid placeholder it does not get replaced.

EDIT:

Here is the method of my class which does the replacement:

```
protected function prepare() {
    if (!$this->db) {
        trigger_error (__METHOD__ . ': no Connection available to properly quote the value', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    $this->prepared = str_replace(
        array_map(array($this, 'getPlaceholderName'), array_keys($this->params)),
        array_map(array($this->db, 'quote'), array_values($this->params)),
        $this->original
    );

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `bindValue` just inserts a key => value pair in the internal parameters array, it is not responsible for actual replacement in string, which is done by the `prepare` method, which I'll post in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a single call to good old [strtr()](http://php.net/strtr) whith the array signature:

> string strtr ( string $str , array $replace_pairs )

Of course, plain string replacement is just a hack and can never replace a proper SQL parser, but I guess you already know that.

Comment: Isn't `strtr` only for single chars?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you want to use:

```
$queryString = strtr($queryString, array(":a" => "b",":b"=>"c", ":c" => "a"));
```